# Disadvantages of .toStringing node.js server side functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, tostring

So, I first started `.toString`'ing a couple of validation functions, because that way I could use them both on the server side and the client side (awesome!). As I was just about to `.toString()` a function that is only used on the client side (but has to be send dynamically through ajax) I was re-evaluating this approach. For what it's worth it works splendidly in the current setup, but

- Is `.toString()` an expensive function to run?
- Are there any situations in V9 where `.toString()` will return something else than the source code?
- Are there any other dangers I should take into account?

The only advantage in this case is that I can group certain related functions neatly together in a single class/file, but both in this case and the validation case it would also be possible to split it in a seperate .js file which I could `require` in node and serve to the client side directly for client use.

Comment: Guess i don't quite understand why you need to toString them to use on both client and server.

Comment: @KevinB: If you have a class where the `.validate` function has to be run on both the client and server side, but the `.save` should only be available on the server side you either need to split the file into two or you can use `.toString()`. If there is a different solution please do tell me, but the only other approach I can think of is literally reading the file and cutting the function out.

Comment: I would separate it into two parts. The validate portion shouldn't include the save functionality if you want to use it in both places.

Comment: @KevinB: That's as I mentioned in my question a solution, but what I am asking for is reasons why that would be a better solution. After all, purely from a architectural point of view this is far neater.

Comment: I can't think of any issues with using .toString() this way, but i haven't done it myself enough to know for sure. I just don't see how it would be neater. I prefer splitting my code up into smaller parts rather than having large files that perform multiple tasks.

Comment: Look at it this way. Your process has three steps. Client side validation, server side validation, and saving the data to the datastore. validation doesn't require saving the data, and saving the data doesn't require validation. they shouldn't be coupled together.

Comment: @KevinB: This way I have a single class which handles a single object. If the object would be a table I have a single table instance that can validate it's own state, trigger being stored and retrieve it's HTML representation (which just renders a view). There is no difference between client side validation and server side validation, there is state validation and other methods of the class. Saving the data always requires validation. validation however indeed does not require saving the data. That's why validation can be on it's own on the client side, whereas saving can not be on it's own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61302/discussion-between-david-mulder-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge disadvantage of using toString, you don't get any outer contexts of the function.

Something like this wouldn't work toStringed:

```
var validator = require('validator');

exports.validateEmail = function(email) {
    return validator.isEmail(email) && ~email.indexOf('mydomain');
};
```

Tools such as [browserify](http://browserify.org/) can compile server side node to work on the client with a single file without having to do any extra work.